# Device Placement of kernels and biases when using tf.contrib.layers

Tags: tensorflow

Is it possible to tell the layers defined in `tf.contrib.layers` to store the Variables that define the kernels and biases on the CPU (eg. `/cpu:0`) while still executing ops like convolutions on other devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simpler way:

```
def net(x):
    res = tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(x, 10, [3, 3])
    # and define other layers
    return res


with tf.device('/CPU:0'):
    with tf.name_scope('CPU'):
        net(x)
for i in range(num_gpus):
    with tf.device('/GPU:%d' % i):
        with tf.name_scope('GPU_%d' % i):
            with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope(), reuse=True):
                y = net(x)
                loss = ...
                grad = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found a workaround, which lets me keep my model description with layers from `tf.contrib.layer`. The trick is to add Variable nodes to the graph where the layers would expect the variables to be, when creating them using the `get_variable` method.

For example:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops import variables

layer_scope = 'fully_connected'
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    weights = variables.model_variable(layer_scope+'/weights', shape=...)
    biases = variables.model_variable(layer_scope+'/biases', shape=...)

fc = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(some_input, ...)
```

The function `model_variable` can be found [here at the tensorflow github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/variables.py).

Logging the device placement and looking at the graph in tensorboard one can now see, that the variables are placed on the `cpu`, while it is possible to place the other ops inside `fully_connected` on the `gpu`.

Below you can find a script I put together to test this behaviour. When running it will create a folder called `layer_device_placement_summary` where the tensorboard summary and graph can be found.

This is pretty hacky in my opinion, but it looks to me like you do not lose any functionality, while not adding to many lines of code.

I'd be happy about feedback, if anyone would be interested in testing this as well.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops import variables


# Data and ground truth
with tf.variable_scope('inputs'):
    X = tf.random_normal([50, 100], seed=42)
with tf.variable_scope('outputs'):
    Y = tf.to_int32(tf.reduce_mean(X, axis=-1) > 0)
    Y_oneHot = tf.one_hot(Y, 2)

def test_fn ( inputs, num_outputs, layer_scope ):
    '''Implements a FC-layer with parameters on `/cpu:0`.

    To ensure the weights and biases are recognized by the layer I use the fact,
    that the the function `tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected` tries to get the
    variable befor creating it. Thus ensuring the correct scope and name of the
    weights and biases does the trick.
    '''

    in_dimension = inputs.shape.as_list()[-1]

    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        weights = variables.model_variable(
                layer_scope+'/weights',  # <= Ensure correct scope here
                [in_dimension, num_outputs],
                initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(),
                regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(0.1))

        biases = variables.model_variable(
                layer_scope+'/biases',  # <= Ensure correct scope here
                [num_outputs],
                initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(),
                regularizer=None)

    fc = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
            inputs=inputs, 
            num_outputs=num_outputs, 
            scope=layer_scope, # <= Ensure correct scope here
            activation_fn=None)

    return fc

# Create various layers with different scopes.
with tf.variable_scope('model'):
    with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
        fc11 = test_fn( X, 75, 'fc_1')
        fc12 = test_fn( fc11, 50, 'fc_2')

    with tf.device('gpu:1'):
        fc21 = test_fn( fc12, 25, 'fc_3')
        fc22 = test_fn( fc21, 2, 'fc_4')

with tf.variable_scope('loss'):
    loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(logits=fc22, onehot_labels=Y_oneHot)
    # regularization still works:
    loss += tf.add_n(tf.losses.get_regularization_losses())  

with tf.variable_scope('accuracy'):
    equal = tf.equal(tf.to_int32(tf.argmax(fc22, axis=-1)), Y)
    acc = tf.to_float(tf.reduce_mean(tf.to_int32(equal)))

train_op = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(
        loss=loss, 
        global_step=None, 
        learning_rate=1e-4, 
        optimizer='Adam')

summary = tf.summary.merge_all()

# Uncomment below and comment the line below that to get device placement logging
#with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)) as sess:
with tf.Session() as sess:
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('layer_device_placement_summary', sess.graph)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(100):
        if i % 10 == 0:
            a = sess.run(acc)
            l = sess.run(loss)
            s = sess.run(summary)
            writer.add_summary(s, i)
            print "{}:\tacc: {}\tloss: {}".format(i, round(a, 5), round(l, 5))
        sess.run(train_op)
```

### EDIT:

I made a feature request for explicit Variable placement on github. You can follow the discussion here:
[issue9517](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9517)